# Integer overflow with UDL (user defined literal) for __int128 @ min negative value

Tags: c++, c++11, integer-overflow, user-defined-literals, int128

For clarity and simplicity I will shorten the following numbers as follows:

- `−170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,728` as `-170…728`
- `170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,727` as `170…727`

These numbers represent the minimum and maximum values of an 128–bit signed integer (__int128 in `gcc`).

I implemented user–defined literals (raw literals) for this data type since gcc doesn’t offer a way of defining constants of this type: `_u128` for `unsigned __int128` and `_i128` for `__int128`.

The minus character is not part of the UDL, but a unary minus operator applied to the result of the UDL.

So for a `-ddddd_i128` (where `d` is a digit) the UDL computes a **signed** `__int128` with the positive value `ddddd` and then the compiler will apply the unary minus operator to it. So far so good.

The problem is with `-170…128_i128` (which should be a valid value for `__int128`):
the UDL computes the **signed** `__int128` positive number `170…128` which is just outside of the range of `__int128`, resulting in Undefined Behavior (signed integer overflow).

Any solution to represent this number constant with a UDL?

---

My UDL’s are declared (just a non-constexpr, *loopy* version for now) (they are raw literals):

```
unsigned __int128 operator"" _u128(char const *str);
__int128 operator"" _i128(char const *str);
```

Some usages:

```
  1000000000000000000000000000000000_i128
  -1000000000000000000000000000000000_i128
  -170141183460469231731687303715884105728_i128 // <-- this has UB
  170141183460469231731687303715884105727_u128
  340282366920938463463374607431768211455_u128
```

---

I know that there are ways of defining the constant `-170…728` with various ways, like bit shifts, mathematical operations, but I want to be able to create it in a consistent way, e.g. I don’t want this situation: you can create any constant using this UDL, except for `-170…728_i128`, for which you have to use extra tricks.

Comment: Is `(__int128)1<<127`  considered a UDL? What about `~MAX_INT128`, where `MAX_INT128` is the UDL that is working for you?

Comment: How is your UDL defined? AFAIK, you cannot have a parameter type that is larger than `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Praetorian you are thinking about cooked literals. Raw literals give every digit individually in a C-string, so you are not bound by types (like `long long`)

Comment: @barakmanos (__int128)1<<127 is not an UDL

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/Chud-sdo7uA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially the same problem that implementors have when implementing `<limits.h>`: `INT_MIN` cannot be defined (on a typical 32-bit system) as `-2147483648`. It can be (and commonly is) defined as `(-2147483647 - 1)` instead. You'll have to do something similar. There may not be any way to represent the most negative number with a single negation operator and literal, but that's okay: there is simply no need for it.

Comment: so you are saying that if I write the constant `-2147483648` (in a system where int is 32-bits) that’s UB?

Comment: @bolov No, but `2147483648` will have type `long long`, so the expression does not have the intended meaning. FWIW, the `long long` version (typically `-9223372036854775808`) is invalid. Not undefined behaviour, but if there is no signed integer type that can hold `9223372036854775808`, then using `9223372036854775808` is always an error.

Comment: @bolov: `-2147483648` is not a literal. It's an expression consisting of a literal `2147483648` with a unary `-` operator applied to it. The unary `-` can overflow.

Comment: Right.  INT_MAX is 2147483647.